# Can't get time in scheduleTaskExecutor

Tags: android, calendar, task

I have a problem I don't understand, I use scheduleTaskExecutor to do a task every minute, and I want to update a TextView showing the time when the task was done last.

So here is my scheduleTaskExecutor:

```
public void timed() {
   ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
      // This schedule a runnable task every minute
      scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            doMyTask();
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

And here is how I update my TextView in doMyTask:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mnts = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String heure = String.format("%02d:%02d", hrs, mnts);

TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);   time.setText("(heure);
```

So I really don't know why the time won't be updated when my task is ran with scheduleTaskExecutor, but it works when I run the same task with a button...
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: UI elements should only be updated on the main thread. You might want to use a `Handler` instead of a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, as there is no need to create a thread pool just do a minor UI modification.

Comment: Thank you, but I do need to use  [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor] for some other things I do with the timer. Is there a way to update a TextView anyway?

Comment: Then use a `Handler` to post a `Message` or `Runnable` to the UI thread, and change the UI elements from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!
Here is the code I use, and it works just fine:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hrs = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mnts = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
String heure = String.format("%02d:%02d", hrs, mnts);
TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
time.setText("Mis à jour à : " + heure + " - (occupé)");
}});
```

I hope it can be useful to someone :)